# Can rails 4.2 create an object buried in a nested hash on a call to update in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Say I have a Person object in Rails 4.  In my controller, I do:

@person.update(person_params)

where person_params is a hash like:

```
{ "name" => "Joe",
   magazines_attributes => {
      "2" => { "title" => "Bullet News",
             magazine_subscription_attributes { "price" => "37.50" }
              }
    }
}
```

Is it possible for Rails 4 to create a Magazine subscription via the update method above (and considering that it's nested) or do I have to create it first?  The reason I'm asking is I have a nested form and being able to do this would be really handy.  Person already exists as does Magazine, it's MagazineSubscription that will be a brand new object.

I'm working with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what databse You re working with, its doable with **MongoDB**. But for with **sqllite**  you  ll have to create them your own

Comment: Interesting, I'm working with Postgres if that makes a difference

Comment: Never worked with it before but as far as I know MongoDb hold that privilege for itself

Answer (score 0):

I think it is doable with postgresql. You can have a look on activerecord model association nested attributes. Since I have no idea o your modal relationship (one to one or many to many), you'd better figure it out yourself with the resource below or update your question with more details if you still cannot get there.

[ActiveRecord NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)